# how to traverse parent node till root element in xml in c#

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to access parent node hierarchy till root element from child element in C# and want to store it in string.

In the below xml, I would like to access parent nodes of the `<watchVideo>` element but I don't want to include the root tag in my string and the output should be like this:

```
herobanner.landing.copies.watchvideo
```

My xml format is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>  
  <country>en-in</country>
  <heroBanner>
    <landing>
      <copies>
        <watchVideo>watch the video</watchVideo>
        <scrollDown>READ INSPIRING STORIES</scrollDown>
        <scrollDown/>
        <banner>make your</banner>
        <banner>first move this</banner>
        <banner>valentine's Day</banner>
      </copies>
      <background>
        <desktop>assets/images/millions-hero-1.jpg</desktop>
      </background>
      <foreground>
        <desktop/>
      </foreground>
      <video>
        <youtubeId>buwcDIcFR8I</youtubeId>
      </video>
    </landing>
  </heroBanner>
</root>
```

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far. It doesn't help that we don't even know which XML library you're using - I'd recommend LINQ to XML (which makes this a one-liner). Also, please post your actual XML text, not what shows up in a browser with all those extra `-` before each element. Next, indent the whole XML four spaces so that it shows up properly - look at the preview before you hit post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, to get from one `XElement` to its parent, you can just use the `Parent` property - but in this case you want all the ancestors, so you can use the `AncestorsAndSelf()` method. That returns the ancestors in reverse document order, but you want it in document order (outermost first) so you can just reverse the sequence. Then you know the first element will be the root - you can skip that by calling `Skip(1)`. Then you just need to select the element names, and join them together. So:

```
var names = element.AncestorsAndSelf()
                   .Reverse()
                   .Skip(1) // Skip the root
                   .Select(x => x.Name);
var joined = string.Join(".", names);
```

Complete program:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
        var element = doc.Descendants("watchVideo").First();
        var names = element.AncestorsAndSelf()
                   .Reverse()
                   .Skip(1) // Skip the root
                   .Select(x => x.Name);
        var joined = string.Join(".", names);
        Console.WriteLine(joined);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
heroBanner.landing.copies.watchVideo
```

Note that I *haven't* lower-cased it, but I assume you can do that if you really want to.

Comment: Thanks for this..It really helps. Could you pls tell me if i want to iterate each child. How we can achieve this? For e.g. 1) heroBanner.landing.copies.watchVideo 2) heroBanner.landing.copies.scrolldown 3) heroBanner.landing.copies.banner 4) heroBanner.landing.copies.banner

Comment: @John: You're now asking follow-up questions. That's a really bad fit for Stack Overflow. One question per post. I've shown you how to go from a single element to the format you want. Now you should do some research on how to use LINQ to XML to traverse elements. Any LINQ to XML tutorial should be able to help you.

Comment: I've applied foreach to traverse in doc.Descendants() and store all the elements in list. After that i can use your linq query for each Descendant. Thanks Jon for great help, You've saved my time.